# Telephoto stitching Android app, to photograph distant flat buildings

Tags: android, photography, stitching

I often take pictures of **distant buildings** with a Pixel 6/7/8 Pro Android phone which has a **4x optical zoom (telephoto)**.

The building is typically a bit too high and large to take in a single 4x shot, but fits in 4 shots:

[image]

**Question**: What app helps me take the necessary shots, and stitches them into a high-quality JPG file?

Notes:

- If I use the 2x zoom, the building is fully covered in a single shot, but it severely lacks details.
- The stock camera's `Panorama` and `Photo Sphere` modes do not let me switch to the 4x lens.
- I am only shooting far-away flat objects, no foreground/background, so 2D stitching is probably enough. No need for sphere-like output, as my goal is to export a 2D JPG.
- The level of details should be as close as possible as what the 4x lens gives.
- Bonus if the app shows me a preview that guides me to fully cover the building.
- Below 50$, great if gratis, wonderful if open source.

Answer (score 1):

[Bimostitch Panorama Stitcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.rethinkvision.Bimostitch) usually does a decent job at stitching pictures. There is a gratis ad-supported version and a paid version with more features.

Drawbacks:

- Does not guide you, so it is difficult to be sure you have covered the whole building.
- Sometimes gets confused, stitching pictures at the incorrect place.

The quality of the final JPG output is very close to the quality of the 4x input pictures.